# Why is pppoe connection working on Linux laptop but not on Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows, networking, linux-mint

Tried every possible solution I found on the web, including restarting the modem (I have only that).

Been resetting network on Windows PC, uninstalling, reinstalling the adapter, installing it from motherboard's CD, turn on/off adapter, fool around with all kinds of half duplex and full duplex settings...nothing. Restarted PC like 15 times after I made changes.

Opened cmd as admin and typed in:
Wrote ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew...nothing.

Wrote nbtstat -R, nbtstat -RR, netsh ont ip reset C:\resetlog.txt and netsh winsock reset...nothing

Wrote netsh winsock reset and netsh int ip reset...nothing

Installed a Protocol on Adapter settings (the only one that was there)...nothing

Disabled IPv6...nothing

What could be the problem when this connection works flawlessly on Linux laptop but on Windows PC it says "The modem (or other connnecting device) has reported an error." When I clicked diagnose on the adapter it said it doesn't have a valid IP configuration.
On laptop this cable is green all the time when it's on, yet on Windows 10 PC it's green and blinking with orange light. I don't know why would it be ISPs problem and heard from others they just recommend turning the adapter on and off...

I have done no OS installation on any of them, the problem just appeared one day when I switched on the PC.

Comment: Can you please clarify (you can edit the extra information into your question) the following: In the title you mention pppoe which is a protocol to connect to (and login to) the internet connection. This can happen inside the modem/router, in which case the computer needs to be configured for standard IP with DHCP. Or it can be done on the computer side in which case some special configuration must be setup on the computer side. Which is the case here? (All your troubleshooting steps are valid if it is the first case. They don't make a difference in case 2.)

Comment: on Windows 10 PC it's green and blinking with orange light.  .......   Try a new (different) USB LAN adapter and see if that works.